# Extract Images and their Labels from PDFs

Tags: image, parsing, pdf

I am facing a problem extracting images with their labels (not metadata!) from pdf files. By label I mean the text that is assigned to the image to describe it regeardless of it's possition, underneath or above. I've tried alot of known parsers, such as iText, Tika, PDFbox and pdf2html but i found no way of how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: PDF isn't like HTML, i.e. there is no <CAPTION>. Text near an image is just text.

Comment: yeah I know that but out of desperation I posted this question here and I was thinking in the direction of maybe having some kind of an algorithm that calculates margins, position etc. There must be some solution to this problem, somewhere.